# Reorder a list whenever it is viewed depending on filters

Tags: sharepoint-online, list-view

new to Sharepoint, although I have managed to get most of my project working but I am stumped on a very important part.
I have 3 main lists; Problems, Devices and Steps. Problems and Devices are used to filter Steps, so I end up with a list of steps to troubleshoot a problem for a certain device.
The hard part is, I want Steps list to be ordered depending on the filters used to view it, i.e.

- If I filter with problem 1 and device 1, I want steps listed as: 1,
  2, 3
- If I filter with problem 1 and device 2, I want steps listed as
  1, 4, 2, 3

Any ideas?

Lists so far:

```
    Steps        Devices      Problems
    ----------   ---------    ---------
    Title        Title        Title
    Devices
    Problems
    SortOrder
```

Steps List is filtered using Devices:Title and Problems:Title.
At the moment SortOrder is a fixed value that almost works, but reduces the flexability of the List.
If SortOrder was found in another list it would work much better:

```
    SortOrder
    ---------
    Devices
    Problems
    DisplayedOrder
```

Using the above list I want multiple LookUps of SortOrder in Steps and to choose the one that matches the Devices and Problems filter I am using. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to use a list to dictate the sort order something like this

```
|Device|Problem|Step|DisplayOrder|
==================================
|1     |1      |1   |1           |
|1     |1      |3   |3           |
|1     |1      |2   |2           |
|2     |1      |1   |1           |
|2     |1      |2   |3           |
|2     |1      |3   |4           |
|2     |1      |4   |2           |
```

This would then let you pull the data back the way you want it and still allow you to use lookups to generate the lists.  It also means you can easily add/change the display order as you want.